# A function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]\times [0,1]$ that is not continuous such that $\pi \circ f$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to find a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]\times [0,1]$ such that $f$ is not continuous, but the composition $\pi \circ f$ is continuous.
Here $\pi: [0,1]\times [0,1] \rightarrow T$ is a quotiënt map of the Torus. (It doesn't really matter which one.) 
I hope somebody can help me out!

Edit: I have the following proposed solution for $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]\times [0,1]$. Let $f(x)=(x,x)$ if $x\leq \frac{1}{4}$ or $x\geq \frac{3}{4}$ and $f(x) =(0,0)$ for all other $x\in Dom(f)$. I'm not hundred percent sure if this is correct. Am I on the right track?

Comment: It is slightly less confusing to replace the target of $f$ by $[0,1]$ and $\pi$ to be a quotient onto  $\mathbb{S}^1$ . Solve the new problem and then you can extend the construction to solve your original problem

Comment: Thanks I think I was able to do it with this idea. I'm new to this site so I don't know if I can send you a private message so I can check what I did was correct?

Comment: There is no pm as far as I know, but usually one would be editing his question with the exposition of a potential solution.

Comment: Okay, I'll quickly do that @Mihail

Answer (score 3):

Take a square of paper, and think about how you should glue it together to get a torus. From that, think on how you can draw a continuous line on the torus that is not continuous on the square of paper.

Comment: Should I then try to draw a line on the torus that breaks when you reverse the gluing process? If so I'm struggling imagining a line on the torus for which this is the case

Comment: Yes. Any line that passes through the glued regions(which are 2 circles intersecting in a point) on a torus will work.